# HTML - "Top Level and Second Level" List

Tags: html, css, list

I have the following list on my html file: I need to know how I can make the Headings: The Road To War; Politicians and Generals;  The Course of war; and Afermath in Upper-Roman and the subheadings under each one in Upper-Alpha, within my css file.

```
<nav class="vertical">
     <h4>Course Outline</h4>
     <ol>
        <li><a href="#">The Road to War</a>
           <ol>
              <li><a href="#">Planting the Seeds</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">The First Crisis</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Compromise &amp; Failure</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fault Lines</a></li>
           </ol>
        </li>            
        <li><a href="#">Politicians &amp; Generals</a>
           <ol>
             <li><a href="#">Politicians</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Generals</a></li>
           </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">The Course of War</a>
           <ol>
              <li><a href="#">1861-1862</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">1863</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">1864-1865</a></li>
           </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Aftermath</a>
           <ol>
              <li><a href="#">Lincoln Assassination</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reconstruction</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">A New Constitution</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">The United States Is ...</a></li>
           </ol>
        </li>
     </ol>
  </nav>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar Deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the ol you want to make it Upper-alpha for example `<ol class="alpha">` and then in css:

```
.alpha {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of them classes and do like this 
for upper roman

```
ol{
list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

for upper alpha

```
ol{
list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```